# Programmatically detect changes to a table row

Tags: c++, mysql, database

Is there a way to programmatically detect if a certain row has changed in a database table?

I want my application to know the instant that a table row has been modified.  I can always do a standard query update loop, yet I was wondering if there was a better easier way that I am overlooking.

Comment: Triggers maybe? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: That would require some kind of event. Interesting question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only mechanism currently supported by MySQL is a trigger. You can set a trigger to happen when an update occurs, and use that trigger to do something to notify your application using sys_exec() or similar.

Note that the update trigger only catches when an update is made through SQL, not otherwise (such as APIs, NDB, for example).

Comment: My application is a daemon so it always has to be running.

I guess I could have a trigger make a system call, which can be caught by an epoller running on my daemon and execute the corresponding code, which would be a pretty fast detection method.

Comment: Why is there a downvote on this answer? If you're going to downvote something, please state your reasons so we can learn from them and/or discuss them.